# Read file.inputstream twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to read csv file twice. but after first reading:

```
using (var csvReader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
{
    fileFullText += csvReader.ReadToEnd();
    file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    csvReader.Close();
}
```

using file in enother function:

```
public static List<string> ParceCsv(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (var csvReader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
    {
       // csvReader.DiscardBufferedData();
       // csvReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string inputLine = "";
        var values = new List<string>();

        while ((inputLine = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            values.Add(inputLine.Trim().Replace(",", "").Replace(" ", ""));
        }
        csvReader.Close();
        return values;
    } 
}
```

The file.Length is 0. 
Can anybody help?

Comment: According to your code you only read it once, please update your code.

Comment: you don't need to call csvReader.Close();, it will be closed by using statement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that `SteramReader`'s `Dispose()` method also closes the underlying stream; In your case `file.InputStream`. The `using` statement calls `Dispose()` implicitly. Try to replace using with disposes of both your `StreamReaded`-s after you finished both read operations. As I remember some stream classes have a bool option to leave underlying stream open after dispose.

.NET 4.5 fixed this issue by introducing `leaveOpen` parameter in `SteamReader` constructor. See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

```
public StreamReader(
    Stream stream,
    Encoding encoding,
    bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks,
    int bufferSize,
    bool leaveOpen
)
```

One more thing. You do not need to close `SteramReader` yourself (the line with `csvReader.Close();`) when you wrap it in `using` statement, thus `Dispose()` and `Close()` are the same in case of `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 2):

if your using HttpPostedFileBase you need to clone it first,
use the code this git [here](https://gist.github.com/terjetyl/1613007)
or just add this as a class in your namespace:

```
public static class HttpPostedFileBaseExtensions
{
    public static Byte[] ToByteArray(this HttpPostedFileBase value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        var array = new Byte[value.ContentLength];
        value.InputStream.Position = 0;
        value.InputStream.Read(array, 0, value.ContentLength);
        return array;
    }
}
```

now you can read the HttpPostedFileBase like so:

```
private static void doSomeStuff(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new MemoryStream(file.ToByteArray()))
        {
            // do some stuff... say read it to xml
            using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
            {                    

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

after using this you can still write in your main code:

```
file.SaveAs(path);
```

and it will save it to the file.